# Trouble With GROUP BY Learning Derby SQL

Tags: sql, derby

I have formed this query to produce the pitcher from each team who has the most wins.  My trouble comes in that I need to group them a certain way and I keep having scoping issues when trying to do so.  W is the number of wins for each pitcher.  Here is my pre-grouped statement...

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT p1.nameFirst FROM Players p1 Where (one.playerID = p1.playerID)), 
    (SELECT p1.nameLast FROM Players p1 Where (one.playerID = p1.playerID)), 
    one.W, (SELECT t1.name FROM Teams t1 Where(one.teamID = t1.teamID)) 
 FROM Pitching one
 Where (one.W >= ALL
    (SELECT two.W
    FROM Pitching two
    Where (two.teamID = one.teamID)));
```

I need to group the tuples by league and within the leagues group by division.  League (lgID) and division (divID) exist in the Teams table.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thank you.

This is top six rows of what is currently output...

```
Zach    Britton         11  Baltimore Orioles
Mark    Buehrle         13  Chicago White Sox
Madison Bumgarner       13    San Francisco Giants
Jhoulys Chacin          11  Colorado Rockies
Bruce   Chen            12  Kansas City Royals
Kevin   Correia         12  Pittsburgh Pirates
```

My desired output is to have these teams sorted by league (NL/AL) and within the leagues have them sorted by division.

Comment: post some sample data n ur desired o/p... ur query is completely wrong...

Comment: Have you considered providing feedback on this question first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629100/learning-sql-is-there-a-better-way-to-write-this
3 people answered...  You might get some more responses if you were interactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated comment.  I think this is what you want.

```
SELECT
   pl.nameFirst
   , pl.nameLast
   , p.W
   , t.name
FROM
(
    SELECT
        MAX(p1.W) AS W
        , p1.teamId
    FROM
    Pitching p1
    GROUP BY
        p1.teamId
) t1
JOIN
    Pitching p
       ON t1.W = p.W
       AND t1.teamId = p.teamId
JOIN
   Players pl
     ON p.playerID = pl.playerID
JOIN
   Teams t
     ON p.teamID = t.teamID
ORDER BY
   t.lgID
   , t.divID
```

I do agree with swasheck, there are some opportunities for improvement in your schema.  As swascheck said, teamId should be in Players.  Not in Pitching.

Comment: well, the first name and last name come from a player table. the structure is extremely flawed

Comment: yeah, late in the day.  Missed the ONs as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  This groups them properly, but produces all pitchers from all teams.  My original query produces only the pitcher with the most wins from each team.  I'm brand new to all this, so sorry for my poor structure.

Comment: oh dear. would you please edit the question to reflect these requirements?

Comment: additionally, would you please post a bit more about the structure? there is nothing in your original query that would lead us to believe that there is any counting going on.

Comment: @MichaelRice I hope that you're right and he doesn't have to aggregate the wins first, and then get the max on that.

Comment: @swasheck I'm not sure what the right answer is as it's a moving target. :-)

Comment: that works perfectly and is much cleaner to read.  I've got lots to learn.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue of structure. Using what I believe to be your structure we could probably narrow it down like this:

```
 select Players.nameFirst, Players.nameLast, TopPitcher.Winner, 
  Teams.name, League.Name, Division.Name
    from    (select playerID, max(Wins) as Winner
    from (select playerID, teamID, count(W) as Wins
        from Pitching
        group by playerID, teamID ) PitchingWins) TopPitcher       
    join Players 
    on TopPitcher.playerID = Players.playerID 
    join Teams 
    on Teams.teamID = Players.teamID
    join League 
    on Teams.leagueID = League.leagueID
    join Division 
    on League.divisionID = Division.divisionID
    order by League.Name, Division.Name
```

Now. Having said that, this is only for the structure you've given (with some other interpolation). Your overall structure is faulty as I would probably relate Player to Teams and not Pitching to Teams since you might get some sort of data errors regarding team wins vs. pitcher wins.

Comment: Won't grouping on the playerId cause a problem in your aggregate?  As you are not aggregating the team, your aggregating the player.

Comment: hm. initially i agreed with you, but my understanding is that he wants the winningest pitcher from each team ... so we need both.